# Is using dpkg a must for using unattended-upgrades?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

I've installed *unattended-upgrades* via `sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades`.

I understand from the `man` that after doing `sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades`, one should do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
```

Is it a must or is it just a recommendation to go from "high" or "medium" to "low"?

It's not clear to me from the man:

1. If it's only in the level of "recommendation" or must be done to start working with the program.
2. What is changed by `reconfigure` to low? Is it "medium" or "high" level of upgrades?

Comment: It's not very clear what's confusing you. The purpose of `dpkg-reconfigure` is, as its name implies, to configure the software. Presumably, you could also do it by editing config files by hand, but `dpkg-reconfigure` will be more user-friendly.

Comment: It is just a reccomendation

Comment: I misread the command, rarely unnoting the "re" just before the "configure". So it only reconfigures unattended-upgrades. Is it "high" or "medium" (or something else) by default? before running `dpkg-reconfigure`?

Comment: Is it the flag `--priority` in particular that's confusing you? If so, I'll write an answer about that (you may also want to edit the question to make that point clearer).

Comment: The priority is not very intuitive, I'm not confused by that, I just don't know what is the original priority that is changed by reconfigure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first install a package, you are sometimes asked some questions about how you plan to use it; your answers to those questions are then used by the system to do some initial configuration of the package. The command `dpkg-reconfigure` is used when you want the system to ask you those questions again after installing the package, for example when you change your mind about some of them.

The questions are divided into four priority levels as follows (from `man 7 debconf`*):

```
low    Very trivial questions that have defaults that will work in the vast majority of cases.

medium Normal questions that have reasonable defaults.

high   Questions that don't have a reasonable default.

critical Questions that you really, really need to see (or else).
```

The `--priority` flag of `dpkg-reconfigure` lets you specify the minimal priority level of the questions you will be asked; for example `--priority=high` says you want to be asked only the questions whose priority level is `high` or higher, and not be bothered by lower-priority questions. This is what happens automatically when you first install the package.

The source you have been reading, however, considers that, for the package `unattended-upgrades`, it is important that you answer the `low`- and `medium`-priority questions as well. Since you are not asked those questions during installation, it therefore recommends that you run `dpkg-reconfigure` with `--priority=low` afterwards.

---

* This `man` page is not installed by default; it is available in the package `debconf-doc` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/debconf.7.html).